# sum value from table as I keep on adding data in java swing

Tags: java, swing

When I add data to the `JTable`, the 5th column(i.e. quantity) needs to be summed as I keep on adding data and should display the sum in`JLabel`.

> **Getting following** Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        //fetching data from textfield and adding to tblList.
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblList.getModel();
        int no = tblList.getRowCount();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add(Integer.toString(no + 1));
        list.add(txtName.getText());
        list.add(txtManufacturer.getText());
        list.add(txtGroup.getText());
        list.add(txtQty.getText());

        model.addRow(list.toArray());
        no++;

        totalProducts();

        clearText();
    }


public void totalProducts() {
        int row = tblList.getRowCount();

        //fetching the 4th column data(i.e quantity) and adding till data exits.
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            total = Integer.parseInt(tblList.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
            totalQty = totalQty + total;
        }

        System.out.println("total = " + totalQty);

        lblTotal.setText(String.valueOf(totalQty));
    }
```

Comment: So what is happening if you run this code? Any error or something?

Comment: i am getting  - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            total = Integer.parseInt(tblList.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
            totalQty = totalQty + total;
        }
```

In this code you use **row** in  `getValueAt(row, 4)` soudnt that be `getValueAt(i, 4)` ? since you dont use **i** at all in your loop its pointless and i bet **"row" index** is outside of the boud of the array based on your condition.

for example if

```
int row = tblList.getRowCount(); //returns 10
```

Last index will be 9 and you access 10 every time in your loop.